# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

This is a function to convert 1 digit number to 3 digit. For example convert '2' to '002'.

```
void loop() {
 int x = convertdigit(time);
}

void convertdigit(int num){
  char buffer[50];
  int n;
  n=sprintf (buffer, "%03d",num);
  return buffer;
}
```

Error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

```
/sketch/sketch.ino: In function 'void loop()':
/sketch/sketch.ino:33:30: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     int x = convertdigit(time);
                              ^
Error during build: exit status 1
```

May i know how to fix it?

Comment: The opposite is interesting as well: sprintf does return something, but you don't care. In this case you can omit `int n; n= `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this you are telling the compiler that `convertdigit` does not return anything (void):

```
void convertdigit(int num)
```

When you write this, you are telling the compiler to use the return value of `convertdigit` and store it in `x`:

```
int x = convertdigit(num);
```

Those two things are in conflict: if `convertdigit` doesn't return anything, how can you store that nothing in `x`?  Your code is kind of confusing so I'm not sure what you actually intended, but now that I have explained that error message, I hope you are able to make progress.

Hint: If you want `convertdigit` to return an `int`, change `void convertdigit(...` to `int convertdigit(...`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It works for me.

Comment: It should not work for your question:  "001" is not an `int` but a text.

Answer (score 1):

You should distinguish numbers ( 2 ) from texts "002"

```
void loop() {
 static byte n = 1; 
 char* txt = convertdigit(n); // Convert to a 2 character text with a leading zero, if necessary;
 Serial.println(txt);
 delay(100); 
 n++; 
 if (n > 99) n=0; 
}

char* convertdigit(byte num) {
   static char buffer[4];
   sprintf (buffer, "%02d", num);
   return buffer;
}
```

`static` is required to keep the variable available after function has ended (similar to global variables):

`n` keeps its incremented value in the next loop round.

`buffer` is available via return value after `converdigit()` returns.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try it later.